# Qemu: How can I get a Bash?

Tags: linux, qemu, arm

I have a file system directory file/ and a kernel file zImage. At first, I converted the file system directory to SquashFS format.

I used the following command for this:

```
mksquashfs file file.squashfs
```

Then I used the following command to run them using Qemu:

```
qemu-system-arm -M virt-2.9 -kernel zImage -netdev user,id=net1,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net1 -drive file=file.squashfs,if=virtio,format=raw -append "root=/dev/vda"
```

But Bash was not shown to me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySgQJ.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.